# JSON Parse (Retrofit2)

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

При запросе приходят вот такие данные:

```
{"status":"ok",
"data":{
   "1":{
      "statistics":{
         "all":{"wins":1941}
      },
      "nickname":"nickname1",
      "account_id":1
   }
   "2":{
      "statistics":{
         "all":{"wins":133}
      },
      "nickname":"nickname2",
      "account_id":2
   }
   ...
}}
```

Здесь 1, 2 - account_id. На сервер повлиять не могу. Не получается правильно прописать в классе то, что находится в data. То есть я даже не могу вытащить account_id и nickname. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ предлагает создать классы _1, _2 и т.д., но это неверно (наверное).

```
public class PlayerInfoResponse {
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Или может я неправильно делаю запрос?

```
public interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("account/list/")
    Observable<AccountResponse> getAccounts(@Field("application_id") String appId, @Field("search") String nickname);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("account/info/")
    Observable<PlayerInfoResponse> getPlayerInfo(@Field("application_id") String appId, @Field("account_id") Integer accountId);
}
```

```
public Observable<AccountResponse> getAccounts(String nickname) {
   return App.getApi().getAccounts(appId, nickname);
}
public Observable<PlayerInfoResponse> getPlayerInfo(Integer accountId) {
   return App.getApi().getPlayerInfo(appId, accountId);
}
```

```
Observable<AccountResponse> observable = remoteRepository.getAccounts(nickname);

observable
                .flatMap(accountResponse -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "first: " + accountResponse.getAccountData().get(0).getNickname());
                    return remoteRepository.getPlayerInfo(accountResponse.getAccountData().get(0).getAccountId());
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .subscribe(new Observer<PlayerInfoResponse>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}

                               @Override
                               public void onNext(PlayerInfoResponse playerInfoResponse) {
                                   Log.d(TAG, "second: " + playerInfoResponse.getStatus());
                                   searchCallback.onNext(playerInfoResponse);
                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onError(Throwable e) { }

                               @Override
                               public void onComplete() {
                                   searchCallback.onComplete();
                               }
                });
```

PS: прошу не обращать внимание на `...getAccountData().get(0)...` пытался тестировать только с первым найденным аккаунтом, в последующем будет отправляться список.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужны примерно такие модели. Аннотации и методы доступа к полям допишите сами.

```
class PlayerInfoResponse {
    String status;
    HashMap<String, Data> data;
}

class Data {
    int account_id;
    String nickname;
    Statistics statistics;
}

class Statistics {
    All all;
}

class All {
    int wins;
}
```